# How to rewrite in point-free style with a repeating variable?

Tags: haskell, pointfree, tacit-programming

How to rewrite the following expression in point-free style?

```
p x y = x*x + y
```

Using the lambda-calculus I did the following:

```
p = \x -> \y -> (+) ((*) x x) y
  = \x -> (+) ((*) x x) -- here start my problem
  = \x -> ((+) . ((*) x )) x
  ... ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned Lambda Calculus I will suggest how to solve this with SK combinators. η-reduction was a good try, but as you can tell you can't η-reduce when the variable is used twice.

```
S = λfgx.fx(gx)
K = λxy.x
```

The feature of duplication is encoded by `S`. You simplified your problem to:

```
λx.(+)((*)xx)
```

So let us start there. [Any lambda term can be algorithmically transformed to a SK term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis).

```
T[λx.(+)((*)xx)]
= S(T[λx.(+)])(T[λx.(*)xx])        -- rule 6
= S(K(T[(+)]))(T[λx.(*)xx])        -- rule 3
= S(K(+))(T[λx.(*)xx])             -- rule 1
= S(K(+))(S(T[λx.(*)x])(T[λx.x]))  -- rule 6
= S(K(+))(S(*)(T[λx.x]))           -- η-reduce
= S(K(+))(S(*)I)                   -- rule 4
```

In Haskell, `S = (<*>)` and `K = pure` and `I = id`. Therefore:

```
= (<*>)(pure(+))((<*>)(*)id)
```

And rewriting:

```
= pure (+) <*> ((*) <*> id)
```

Then we can apply other definitions we know:

```
= fmap (+) ((*) <*> id)     -- pure f <*> x = fmap f x
= fmap (+) (join (*))       -- (<*> id) = join for Monad ((->)a)
= (+) . join (*)            -- fmap = (.) for Functor ((->)a)
```

Answer (score 10):

I asked `lambdabot`

```
<Iceland_jack> @pl p x y = x*x + y
<lambdabot> p = (+) . join (*)
```

[`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) is from `Control.Monad` and normally has this type

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

but using `instance Monad ((->) x)` (if we could [left section types](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12477) this could be written `(x ->)`) we get the following type / definition

```
join :: (x -> x -> a) -> (x -> a)
join f x = f x x
```

Let's ask *GHCi* to confirm the type:

```
>> import Control.Monad
>> :set -XTypeApplications 
>> :t join @((->) _)
join @((->) _) :: (x -> x -> a) -> x -> a
```

Answer (score 5):

If you go to http://pointfree.io/

For

```
p x y = x*x + y
```

It gives you

```
p = (+) . join (*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, you can use the `State` monad to write

```
p = (+) . uncurry (*) . runState get
```

`runState get` simply produces a pair `(x, x)` from an initial `x`; `get` copies the state to the result, and `runState` returns both the state and that result.

`uncurry (*)` takes a pair of values rather than 2 separate values (`(uncurry (*)) (3, 3) == (*) 3 3 == 9`).